# Understanding State and Getters in Nuxt.js: Getters won't working

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

i'm new to Vue and Nuxt and i'm building my first website in Universal mode with these framework.

I'm a bit confused on how the store works in nuxt, since following the official documentation i can't achieve what i have in mind.

In my store folder i have placed for now only one file called "products.js", in there i export the state like this:

```
export const state = () => ({

  mistica: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'mistica'
    }
})
```

(The object is simplified in order to provide a cleaner explanation)

In the same file i set up a simple getter, for example:

```
export const getters = () => ({

    getName: (state) => {
      return state.mistica.name
    }
})
```

Now, according to the documentation, in the component i set up like this:

```
computed: {
 getName () {
  return this.$store.getters['products/getName']
 }
}
```

or either (don't know what to use):

```
computed: {
 getName () {
  return this.$store.getters.products.getName
 }
}
```

but when using "getName" in template is "undefined", in the latter case the app is broken and it says "Cannot read property 'getName' of undefined"

Note that in the template i can access directly the state value with "$store.state.products.mistica.name" with no problems, why so?

What am i doing wrong, or better, what didn't i understand?

Comment: why or how are `export const state / getters` functions ? haven't seen this on vuex.vuejs.org - is this nuxt stuff ?

Comment: @birdspider for the state is correct, but as pointed by the guys here for the getters exporting a function is incorrect because getters, actions and mutations are objects. Nuxt has vuex integrated and it uses modules and namespacing by default

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Using factory function for a `state` is a nuxt.js feature. It is used in the SSR mode to create a new state for each client. But for `getters` it doesn't make sense, because these are pure functions of the state. `getters` should be a plain object:

```js
export const getters = {
  getName: (state) => {
    return state.mistica.name
  }
}
```

After this change getters should work.

---

Then you can use the `this.$store.getters['products/getName']` in your components.

You can't use `this.$store.getters.products.getName`, as this is the incorrect syntax.

But to get simpler and more clean code, you can use the `mapGetters` helper from the `vuex`:

```js
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

...

computed: {
  ...mapGetters("products", [
    "getName",
    // Here you can import other getters from the products.js
  ])
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes sense but i didn't even think about it, just copied the syntax without wondering what i was actually doing.

Comment: Another question: For what reason i can access the state with the syntax $store.state.products.mistica.name?

Comment: This is because the state of store modules are merged into the root state object under the keys associated with the names of the modules. However the getters of store modules are prefixed and merged into a single plain array. I'm not really sure why it works this way.

Comment: Thanks a million. Accessing the getters for me using `this.$store.getters.products.getName` seemed cumbersome but the above syntax works

Comment: @NinaLisitsinskaya  Thanks for the answer, but if we have another file in store (like ```user.js```) and want to use getters of both ```product.js``` and ```user.js```, what would be the syntax with the help of ```...mapGetters```?

Answer (score 15):

Couple of things. In your "store" folder you might need an index.js for nuxt to set a root module. This is the only module you can use `nuxtServerInit` in also and that can be very handy.

In your products.js you are part of the way there. Your state should be exported as a function but actions, mutations and getters are just objects. So change your getters to this:

```
export const getters = {
    getName: state => {
      return state.mistica.name
    }
}
```

Then your second computed should get the getter. I usually prefer to use "mapGetters" which you can implement in a page/component like this:

```
<script>
import {  mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      getName: 'products/getName'
    })
}
</script>
```

Then you can use getName in your template with `{{ getName }}` or in your script with `this.getName`.